# Efficient way of shading multiple regions under curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, normal-distribution

I want to plot a normal distribution curve and shade three regions under the curve defined as "average" (between negative one and positive one standard deviations), "above or below average" (between negative two and negative one respectively positive one and positive two standard deviations) and "far above or below average" (between negative three and negative two respectively positive two and positive three standard deviations).

First I looked for a function that can handle the coloring and came across matplotlib's [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) method. I then used `np.linspace` to define the three x-vectors and used a for-loop and `fill_between` to shade the regions. I then realized that `fill_between` will "connect" two regions even if I want the middle part to be unshaded (which applies for "above and below average" and "far above and below average"). So this method doesn't work.

I then came across the `where` keyword argument in `fill_between`and came up with a solution that uses logical operators to define the three regions. This method works but I am not very satisfied with it and have the strong feeling that there must be a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

plotdata = {"mean": 50,"sd": 10}

# plot normal distribution
x_normdist = np.linspace(plotdata["mean"] - 3 * plotdata["sd"], plotdata["mean"] + 3 * plotdata["sd"],1000)
y = norm.pdf(x_normdist,plotdata["mean"],plotdata["sd"])
plt.plot(x_normdist,y)

# create logical lists
average = (x_normdist >= (plotdata["mean"] - 1 * plotdata["sd"])) & (x_normdist <= (plotdata["mean"] + 1 * plotdata["sd"]))

above_and_below_average = (x_normdist >= (plotdata["mean"] - 2 * plotdata["sd"])) & (x_normdist < (plotdata["mean"] - 1 * plotdata["sd"])) | (x_normdist > (plotdata["mean"] + 1 * plotdata["sd"])) & (x_normdist <= (plotdata["mean"] + 2 * plotdata["sd"]))

far_above_and_belowe_average = (x_normdist >= (plotdata["mean"] - 3 * plotdata["sd"])) & (x_normdist < (plotdata["mean"] - 2 * plotdata["sd"])) | (x_normdist > (plotdata["mean"] + 2 * plotdata["sd"])) & (x_normdist <= (plotdata["mean"] + 3 * plotdata["sd"]))

# bind lists
regions = [average,above_and_below_average,far_above_and_belowe_average]

# set alpha values
alpha_values = [0.75,0.5,0.25]

# plot regions with corresponding alpha values
for idx,region in enumerate(regions):
    y = norm.pdf(x_normdist, plotdata["mean"], plotdata["sd"])
    plt.fill_between(x_normdist, y,color="C0",alpha=alpha_values[idx],where=regions[idx])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I personally find your solution/method straightforward and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Bazingaa that you solution is probably good enough and easy to read. If you would like to shade many different intervals, it would get bothersome, though. You could optimize the process like the following, but the code is much less readable.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
m=50.
sd=10.

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(m-3*sd,m+3*sd,1000)
y = norm.pdf(x,m,sd)
ax.plot(x,y,c='C0')

cutoffs = [0,0.25,0.6,1.2,3]  # expressed in sd
colors = ['C0','C1','C2','C3']
alphas = [1.00,0.75,0.50,0.25]

where_x = np.zeros(len(x))
for cut in cutoffs:
    where_x+=np.where(np.abs(x-m)>cut*sd,1,0)
for cond,c,a in zip(range(1,len(cutoffs)),colors,alphas):
    ax.fill_between(x,y,color=c,alpha=a,where=(where_x==cond))
```

[image]